# trying to make ajax call work with php and mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I have the following set up for my ajax call but it is not working when I click on a star (this is a star rating), Although if i access the ajax.php directly it inserts, but the ajax call is not happening.

html in php file

```
   echo '<table>
     <tr>
         <td style="padding:10px;">
         <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="'.$user_id.'">
         <span style="font-size: 20px; vertical-align:top;">Comments</span>
         </td>
         <td style="padding:10px;">
         <textarea name="comments" cols="60" rows="2"></textarea>
         </td>
         <td>
         <div>
          <input name="star1000" value "1" type="radio" class="star"/>
          <input name="star1000" value="2" type="radio" class="star"/>
          <input name="star1000" value="3" type="radio" class="star"/>
          <input name="star1000" value="4" type="radio" class="star"/>
          <input name="star1000" value="5" type="radio" class="star"/> 
          </div>
         </td>
    <tr>
    </table>';
```

JS - being used to send the values

```
   <script>
    $('.star').rating({
        callback: function(value, link) {
          var name = $(this).attr('name');
          var userID = $(this).closest('td').find('input[name="userID"]').val();
          var comments = $(this).closest('td').find('textarea[name="comments"]').val();
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/mywebsite/ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              name: name,
              value: value,
              userID: userID,
              comments: comments
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
              try {
                console.log(response);
              } catch (err) {
                alert(response);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
```

My ajax.php located at http://localhost/mywebsite/ajax.php

```
<?php

      extract($_POST);

    $rate_val = $_POST['value'];
    $user_id = $_POST['userID'];
    $comments =  $_POST['comments'];

    $insert_q = "INSERT INTO ratings (rate_comments, rate_num, option_id, rate_date,user_id) 
                 values  ('$comments','$rate_val','1',now(),'$user_id')";

     include 'opendbconn.php';

              if(!($result = mysql_query($insert_q, $database)))
                {
                    print("Could not execute query!<br/>");
                    die(mysql_error()."</div>
               </div>            
                                 </body>
                                </html>");
                }

     include 'closedbcon.php';
?>
```

Comment: on what event you are calling rating function

Comment: its being called when i click on the 'star' no? here <input name="star1000" value "1" type="radio" class="star"/>  its taking the class

Comment: have you checked with firebug? Does it shows any error?

Comment: give the code where u have bind/calling this  ajax

Comment: its there.. in the html.. its taking the class .star as the event

Comment: Which rating plugin you use (link to the webpage?)? Or if this is one you wrote, could we see the source code?

Comment: oh sure, it's from here http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#

Comment: We cannot really test your code, so you should collaborate. Open Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools. Do you have errors in the Console? In the Net/Network tab, check if the request has been made, check the details, check the response if any. Are both sides (the processing PHP and the caller site) on localhost? Does your `callback` run at all?

Comment: that are both on local host, i will check in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the event click with your function .rating() so javascript knows that it has to execute the function .rating() when ".star" is clicked.

You could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          //other javascript code...

          $('.star').bind('click',function(){
                      //your rating function   
                });
        });
```